# How to regroup set-face-attribute calls

Tags: faces

I find myself applying the same attributes to multiple faces quite often:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'sml/line-number nil :background zenburn/bg-1 :foreground zenburn/fg :weight 'unspecified)
(set-face-attribute 'sml/numbers-separator nil :background zenburn/bg-1 :foreground zenburn/fg :weight 'unspecified)
(set-face-attribute 'sml/col-number nil :background zenburn/bg-1 :foreground zenburn/fg :weight 'unspecified)
```

How can regroup those face attributes and apply them to a list of faces ?

I've tried to define a group:

```el
(defgroup me/sml-numbers '('sml/line-number 'sml/numbers-separator 'sml/col-number)
  "Faces for numbers within `smart-mode-line'.")
```

But `set-face-attribute` takes a face as parameter:

```
set-face-attribute: Invalid face: me/sml-numbers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This has nothing to do with `defgroup`, which is about `defcustom` `:group`. See the Elisp manual, node [`Group Definitions`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Group-Definitions.html).
2. If you insist on grouping here then you need to iterate over the faces using a function that calls `set-face-attribute` on a face (variable) with those other argument values.

For example:

```el
(dolist (face  '(sml/line-number sml/numbers-separator sml/col-number))
  (set-face-attribute face nil
                      :background zenburn/bg-1
                      :foreground zenburn/fg
                      :weight 'unspecified))
```

But what have you really gained by this iteration?  Now if you had 500 such settings to make then maybe...

Comment: My point was to be able to change my smart-mode-line faces with a single line, rather than many. It wouldn't have accomplished much (I won't be changing things too frequently), it was more for educational purposes :), thanks.